# How to remove the grid that fancyhdr creates at first page?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am a novice in using `fancyhdr`. When I use `fancyhdr` it shows a grid on the first page of my pdf. I want to know how can I get rid of it?

I am trying to create a page with 1 inch margin at all sides with page number on top right corner. Here is the minimal code I am using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% To set page numbers at upper right corner
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[R]{1cm}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

% To add 1 inch margin
\oddsidemargin=-1in
\topmargin=-1in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=20pt
\parindent=0pt
\setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headheight}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headsep}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\textwidth{-2in}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
\addtolength\textheight{-2in}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout % 1 inch margin

\raggedright % left justify

\title{My Amazing Paper}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Sample Text
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Sample Text

\end{document}
```

Here is a snapshot of my pdf output: [image]

Comment: Please include the code that produces a grid.  I've never seen that with fancyhdr.

Comment: @JPi Thanks for the comment. Modified the original text.

Answer (score 2):

Remove \layout.  Also, it's better to set margins with the geometry package.

Comment: \geometry has a conflict with another package I am using (I guess endnotes but I am not sure). When I remove the \layout page numbers go to the button again.

Comment: Add \thispagestyle{empty} immediately after \maketitle.  This is a known issue.

Comment: Great! Therefore the total solution was to remove \layout and to add \thispagestyle{empty}. Wonderful and thanks!

Comment: @HamidR.Darabi `geometry` works fine with `endnotes`. At least, it has for me.

Comment: I got a message for package conflict when I added it to the document. I have many other packages already and really didn't want to mess up with what's already there. I might be able to double check which had conflict after I'm done with this submission. Thanks!